# Init checkbox angularjs on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox, ng-init

I've got this situation:

```
<md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">
            <span data-ng-if="itemSelected == undefined || itemSelected == ''">Choose</span>
            <span data-ng-if="itemSelected != '' || itemSelected != undefined">{{itemSelected}}</span>
        </md-subheader>
        <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items">
            <p> {{item.name}} </p>
            <md-checkbox class="md-secondary" ng-init="itemSelection" ng-model="itemSelection" ng-change="changeItemSelected(item)"></md-checkbox>
        </md-list-item>
```

In which i've got a list of items that you can select using a checkbox. 
The function on ng-change is this:

```
$scope.changeItemSelected = function(item) {
        $scope.itemSelected = item.name;
    };
```

When the controller starts, I call a service that get the data checked before. So if the data is not undefined (it means that before something was checked) I set this itemSelection as true. As you can see this variable is used on ng-init. It's working, but not too much. In this way it selects all the checkboxes and not the one i want. I can't reproduce the init call. I created a jsfiddle with this situation by the way
http://jsfiddle.net/2f6qscrp/225/
try to think that when the jsfiddle starts it fires a call to the server to get one of the item selected before. For example i want select the third item of the list. because the server returns the third data like this:

```
{"data":{orange},"meta":{"code":200}}
```

something like that

Comment: Your API returns 1 object. This object should be the checkbox checked. It that right?

Comment: @Mistalis yes. The name of the item that should be selected on init. Only the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I had a function `checkItem()` call in `ng-init`:

```
<md-checkbox class="md-secondary" ng-init="checkItem(item)" 
                                  ng-model="item.checked"                        
                                  ng-change="changeItemSelected(item)">
</md-checkbox>
```

This function checks if a checkbox name correspond to the object returned from your server:

```
$scope.srvValue = { // Value from your server
    "data": "orange",
    "meta": {"code": 200}
};

$scope.checkItem = function(item) {
    if (item.name == $scope.srvValue.data) { // It matchs!
        item.checked = true;
        $scope.changeItemSelected(item);
    }
    else item.checked = false; // It does not
};
```

### [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wp5twprw/)

Comment: Now i try, i'll let you know. Thank you in the while